# Google analytics site search returns "cache" in search term results, why?

Tags: google-analytics, site-search, google-programmable-search-engine

Last week I implemented Google custom search on my website and linked it to a Google analytics view. The site search does not get much traffic as it has been broken for awhile but most of the search term results are:

```
cache:http://www.example/
cache:http://www.example/pagename/
```

Obviously these results are junk but what is going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: *I have just implemented* When? Today? An hour ago? Search engines are not real-time. Using GCS (Google Custom Search) will cause Google to update your site within it's index, however, depending upon your site size. this can still take quite a while. It is possible that you are expecting something unrealistic from Google. Cheers!!

Comment: Implemented last week and by the look of it the site has already been indexed. My test search terms came through as I would expect., but don't know what these other results are.

Comment: I have seen this, however, I cannot for the life of me remember why. It was on another persons site. I will have to think on this a bit. It is possible that Google has not finished all that it needs to do. *Last week* could be Friday(?) which may still not be enough time. Not sure. My site was huge and took several weeks with as many as 64k pages fetched per day. So I do not have a good yard stick for this. The Good news is that Google is highly motivated to make this work quickly and is the only area where Google will bust it's @$$ to make work fast.

Comment: Could [this link be of help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9117513/clear-cache-indexed-pages-of-a-google-custom-search-engine)?

Comment: Did anyone ever find the answer to this question? I've been looking but have had no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is that a cached version of the webpage has been viewed, and due to the way that the Site Search Settings are configured in Google Analytics, this pageview is being counted as a site search.

When you view the cached version of a page from Google's SERPs, the URL is appended with something like: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:RVAzSsB6xI0J:*www.example.com*

The Site Search Settings on the website I was dealing with had been set up to regard the site search query parameter as 'q', meaning that whenever 'q' was detected in a URL, any subsequent characters would be considered to be to be an site search query.

[image: Google Analytics Query Parameter Site Search Settings]

I am going to rectify this by changing the query parameter to be more specific (whilst still matching the correct URL structure) to ensure that **only** true site searches are counted and reported in Google Analytics.

Comment: Hi Hannah, did you get it to work? I seem to have a problem setting query parameter other than "q". The Google CSE doesn't seem to show any result of I set the query parameter to be something else.